# I have a table type field that I need to access to rows individually

Tags: table-field

I'm new using Craft, I have a table type field display on one of my template but I need to display row 2 and 7 in different places of the page how can display only those two rows.

Answer (score 1):

`{{ entry.myTableField[1] }}` and `{{ entry.myTableField[6] }}`

You also might want to check to make sure they exist.

```
{% if entry.myTableField[1] is defined and entry.myTableField[1] is not empty %}
     {{entry.myTableField[1]}}
{% endif %}
```